# how to make animation working only when it is in view

Tags: javascript, html, css

when my page loads the animated element is not in first view.when i scroll to that particular element the animation has already stopped.I want an animation that run only when that element is in view...but without any jquery plugin.Is there any simple JavaScript function for such effect?Thank you in advance.

```
Here is my code < https://jsfiddle.net/6pxwgkro/1/ >
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @HermLuna I tried jquery plugins but it affects my page's other effects and even the animation doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get away without using jQuery but you will need javascript. The best thing that you can do is create an element with a space in it (span, div anything) and use the following code to check if it is in viewport

```
function amIVisible(elem) {
var top = elem.offsetTop;
var left = elem.offsetLeft;
var width = elem.offsetWidth;
var height = elem.offsetHeight;

while(elem.offsetParent) {
elem = elem.offsetParent;
top += elem.offsetTop;
left += elem.offsetLeft;
}

return (
top < (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) &&
left < (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth) &&
(top + height) > window.pageYOffset &&
(left + width) > window.pageXOffset
);
}
```

and if the above function returns true then create the div which needs to be aninamted in js just below the element you checked with a class which does the animation.